# Choosing an encryption protocol for a wireless network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, encryption

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How can I configure my wireless network for the strongest security?](https://superuser.com/questions/1864/how-can-i-configure-my-wireless-network-for-the-strongest-security)
>   [What is the most practical security method for a home wireless network?](https://superuser.com/questions/3180/what-is-the-most-practical-security-method-for-a-home-wireless-network)

I need to configure my wireless network for my desktop. However I am not sure what encryption protocol I should use. Can somebody please let me know if I should use WPA-TKIP, WEP (128 bit), GZIP, WPA-AES or any other?

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/1864/how-can-i-configure-my-wireless-network-for-the-strongest-security and http://superuser.com/questions/3180/what-is-the-most-practical-security-method-for-a-home-wireless-network/3190#3190

Answer (score 3):

WEP and WPA-TKIP are being discontinued due to security vunerabilities. Currently WPA-AES is the only wide-spread secure encryption scheme for WiFi.

http://www.h-online.com/security/news/item/WEP-and-TKIP-Wi-Fi-encryption-methods-to-be-discontinued-1024835.html