# Choosing the correct security settings on Thomson TCW750-4 router

Tags: router, security

Should I leave both WPA-PSK and WPA2-PSK enabled on my Thomson TCW750-4-router? From trying to google it, I get the impression that just leaving the latter enabled will be more secure but that it may cause some issues with older devices? E.g. [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/204697/wi-fi-security-should-you-use-wpa2-aes-wpa2-tkip-or-both/) or [the answers to this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1864/how-can-i-configure-my-wireless-network-for-the-strongest-security?rq=1) seems to say this, but I may be misreading it as I am not very familiar with the lingo. Furthermore, I think I should change the encryption mode from TKIP+AES to just AES - but I figured I should ask if this can cause any issues as well?

This is the intial settings the router came with:

[image]

Oh, and is there any significant benefit to doing this, or did I just start obsessing over insignificant details while all I wanted to do was to change the passcode?

Comment: Leaving it as WPAWPA2-PSK(TKIP/AES) is probably fine for home use, per the article recommends. However, if you want a fuller answer, it may be worth asking over at [security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com) :) (eg see [this question on WPA vs WPA2](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4252/wpa-significantly-less-secure-than-wpa2))

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use WPA2, and if you have problems switch to WPAWPA2. If the network has constantly changing devices, then you are probably fine with WPAWPA2